# How to keep the AngularJS template updated while getting socket updates?

Tags: angularjs, sockets

I get updates from the Backend via socket connections. I want to have an automatically updating Frontend with AngularJS while using a data object  for the data I got from the Backend.

**What do I have?**

Template:

```
Status: {{unit.getStatus()}}
```

Controller 1:

```
function ($scope, unitFactory) {
    // register to unit factory to get the updates and do
    // $scope.unit = data.getUnit();
}
```

Controller 2:

```
function ($scope, unitFactory) {
    // register to unit factory to get the updates and do 
    // $scope.unit = data.getUnit();
    // $scope.foo = data.getFoo();
}
```

Service:

```
function(requestFactory) {
    var unit = {},
        foo = {};

    Sockets.socket('unit', function (response) {
        unit = new Unit(response['data']);
        foo = new Foo(response['foo']);

        // This is the data object which has to be send to the controllers
        var Data = {
            getUnit: function () {
                return unit;
            },

            getFoo: function() {
                return foo;
            }

            // some more functions...
        }
    });
}
```

Sockets:

```
channel.on('data', function (event) {
    try {
        event = JSON.parse(event);      
        // successCallback is what is given as second parameter in the `Service`.        
        $rootScope.$apply(successCallback(event));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

**How should it work together?**

1. Socket update comes in and gets handled by the `Sockets` object
2. `Sockets` call the function which is registered in the `Service`
3. The callback function in `Service` process the data
4. *MISSING* The processed data wrapped in an object has to be delivered to the controllers
5. *MISSING* The controllers can do whatever they want to do with the data whenever there is a new update.
6. The template gets auto updated.

Can anyone help me with the *MISSING* parts? I tried a lot of different approaches but I ran to dead ends every time.

Comment: Have you tried using event rather than callback?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning a promise for the data, and then $state.reload() ?

Comment: How would a promise help me with the socket updates? Until know I've used them only for requests like `get` which are only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved using the 'data model pattern':

Template 1 (used by Controller 1):

```
Status: {{unit.data.getStatus()}}
```

Template 2 (used by Controller 2):

```
Status: {{foo.data.getBar()}}
```

Controller 1:

```
function ($scope, unitFactory) {
    $scope.unit = unitFactory.getUnit();
}
```

Controller 2:

```
function ($scope, unitFactory) { 
    $scope.unit = unitFactory.getUnit();
    $scope.foo = unitFactory.getFoo();
}
```

Service:

```
function(requestFactory) {
    var unit = { data:{} },
        foo = { data:{} };

    Sockets.socket('unit', function (response) {
        unit.data = new Unit(response['data']);
        foo.data = new Foo(response['foo']);
    });

    return                
        getUnit: function () 
            return unit;
        },

        getFoo: function() {
            return foo;
        }
        // some more functions...
    }
}
```

Sockets:

```
channel.on('data', function (event) {
    try {
        event = JSON.parse(event);      
        // successCallback is what is given as second parameter in the `Service`.        
        $rootScope.$apply(successCallback(event));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

Since the data is stored in an object the data in the templates is updated (since it is a reference). I have to get used to these extra attributes `data` and it is not looking nice but it does its job.